# Declaring arrays in c language without initial size

Tags: c, arrays, function

Write a program to manipulate the temperature details as given below.
- Input the number of days to be calculated. – Main function
- Input temperature in Celsius – input function
- Convert the temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit.- Separate function
- find the average temperature in Fahrenheit.

how can I make this program without initial size of array ??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void input(int);
int temp[10];
int d;
void main()
{
    int x=0;
    float avg=0,t=0;
    printf("\nHow many days : ");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    input(d);
    conv();
    for(x=0;x<d;x++)
    {
        t=t+temp[x];
    }
    avg=t/d;
    printf("Avarage is %f",avg);
    getch();
}
void input(int d)
{
    int x=0;
    for(x=0;x<d;x++)
    {
        printf("Input temperature in Celsius for #%d day",x+1);
        scanf("%d",&temp[x]);
    }
}
void conv()
{
    int x=0;
    for(x=0;x<d;x++)
    {
        temp[x]=1.8*temp[x]+32;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your compiler supports c99?

Comment: 1) #include<conio.h> non-standard header 2) `void main()` main() should return int.

Comment: how to check is my compiler supports c99. i'm beginner for C language :)

Comment: BTW: `temp[x]=1.8*temp[x]+32` performs a truncate-towards-zero rounding, biasing inexact results toward 0. Recommend ‘(int) round(1.8*temp[x]+32)’. You'll get a better average in the end. (The usual idiom +0.5 only works here if all conversions are positive.)

Comment: Why the PO does not accept or apparently vote up answers?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In C arrays and pointers are closely related.  In fact, by design an array is just a syntax convention for accessing a pointer to an allocated memory. *(*see note for more details below)*

So in C the statement

```
 anyarray[n]
```

is the same as

```
 *(anyarray+n)
```

Using pointer arithmetic.

**You don't really have to worry about the details to make it "work"** as it is designed to be somewhat intuitive.

Just create a pointer, and allocate the memory and then access it like as an array.

Here is some examples --

```
int *temp = null; // this will be our array


// allocate space for 10 items
temp = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);


// reference the first element of temp
temp[0] = 70;


// free the memory when done
free(temp);
```

Remember -- if you access outside of the allocated area you will have unknown effects.

> - To be clear it is the indexing operator (`[ ]`) that is translated to pointer arithmetic.  This is not an array in the modern sense of the
>     type.  Whether (or not) the pointer involved points to (dynamically) allocated
>     memory is inconsequential to how this operator works.  In a more modern language you would be able to operate on the array as an abstract type (to see how big it is, for example), you can't do this in C.

Comment: is it necessary to explicitly free the memory? what if my array is static?

Comment: @waqaslam - a static array is not dynamic (by definition).  Yes you do need to free the memory.  If you don't you will have a "memory leak" a common bug.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading, [having confused at least one reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59757208/arrays-and-static-pointers) into thinking that after allocation, `temp` would be the identifier of an array.  This is not the case.  An object declared as an `int *` is always and only an `int *`, not an array.  In most ways, the allocated space can be used via the pointer *as if* the pointer were an array, but that doesn't make it one in fact, and there are expressions by which the difference can be detected.  In particular, some involving `sizeof`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger -- I answered this question 7 years ago.   I think it is clear an no where does it say it is array.  I'm happy to update the question to still convey the valuable information but be clearer if you specific suggestion.  I'm not sure why the user thought I said a pointer in C would act like an array in modern strongly typed language.  Maybe that is the real issue -- other languages have changed.

Comment: @Hogan, I know it's an old answer.  I commented because the user who posed a current question (linked in my original comment) misunderstood this answer in just the way I described (they referred specifically to this answer).  I honestly supposed that you would probably ignore the comment, which I think serves as sufficient clarification.  Nevertheless, I do think that "an array is just a syntax convention for accessing a pointer to an allocated memory" indeed is potentially misleading to anyone who doesn't already know what you mean.

Comment: @JohnBollinger -- It was over 20 years ago but when I read it the C book this is what I remember.  It may have changed since then.  If it has, I'd be happy to edit my answer.  My understanding is -- in terms of how the compiler functions -- there is no difference between `anyarray[n]` and `*(anyarray+n)`.   People's expectations have changed and I would never say this about C++.   (Most people these days are using C++ not C.)  I'm not clear on how this can be misleading if it is factual.

Comment: @Hogan, the rule you recall has been well ensconced in the C language standard for more than 30 years.  You are not wrong about it.  The problem -- and I think the source of confusion -- is that it is not "an array" itself that is a syntax convention.  Rather, it is the indexing operator, `[]`.  Secondarily, whether the pointer involved points to (dynamically) allocated memory is inconsequential.

Comment: Sure, @Hogan, be my guest.

Comment: @JohnBollinger -- ok, I hope that make it clearer.  Thanks.

Comment: @Hogan - can we get the size of temp ?

Comment: @scott -- temp is a pointer the size is defined by the OS -- eg a 32 bit OS is 32 bits and a 64 bit OS is 64

Answer (score 5):

An array without an initial size is basically just a **pointer**. In order to dynamically set the size of the array, you need to use the `malloc()` or `calloc()` functions. These will allocate a specified amount of bytes of memory.

In your code above, declare `temp` as an int **pointer**

```
int *temp;
```

Then allocate space for it using `malloc()` or `calloc()`. The argument that these functions take is is the number of **bytes** of memory to allocate. In this case, you want enough space for `d` ints. So...

```
temp = malloc(d * sizeof(int));
```

`malloc` returns a pointer to the first byte in the block of memory that was just allocated. Regular arrays are simply pointers to the first byte in a sectioned off block of memory, which is exactly what `temp` is now. Thus, you can treat the `temp` pointer as an array! Like so:

```
temp[1] = 10;
int foo = temp[1];
printf("%d", foo);
```

Outputs

```
10
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to declare `temp` as an `int` pointer (instead of an `int` array). Then, you can use `malloc` in your `main` (after your first `scanf`):

```
temp = malloc(d * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: i can't understand what you say. i was trying it like this 
printf("\nHow many days : ");
scanf("%d",&d);
int temp[d]; 
but it's not working :(

Comment: You need to change the line `int temp[10]` to `int *temp`. Then, instead of doing `int temp[d]`, use the code I provided in my answer.

Comment: i don't about malloc. can you please tall me how can i use this for my  program.

Comment: `malloc` basically lets you reserve some memory for whatever purpose you need it for, but when you don't know the size ahead of time. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation might be a good place to start

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports `c99`, then simply use **VLA**(variable length array).Use like this:

```
void input(int);

 int d;
 void main()
 {
    int x=0;
    float avg=0,t=0;
    printf("\nHow many days : ");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    int temp[d];
    input(d);
    conv();
    for(x=0;x<d;x++)
    {
       t=t+temp[x];
    }
    avg=t/d;
    printf("Avarage is %f",avg);
    getch();
  }
```

Now `temp[]` is defined inside `main()` after date input.

Comment: @Down voter,it is clear from his post that he has very little knowledge of pointers......keep in mind>

Comment: @user2534857, which compiler are you using?

Comment: @user2534857; Give me information about your compiler/IDE(code::block,Dev-c++,Visual basics etc)

Comment: @Hogan; Then why did't he accepted yet any answer explained by pointer,although answers are correct?

Comment: @haccks you will have to ask him :D

Comment: @user2534857;  Give me information about your compiler/IDE(code::block,Dev-c++,Visual basics etc)

Comment: @Hogan; I am 100% sure he don't have much idea about pointers!

Comment: @user2534857: Either change this old IDE(Read first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961828/why-not-turbo-c) or go with pointers!

Answer (score 1):

1-add `#include<stdlib.h>` at the top of your file. Then modify the conv() code as follows:
2- modify temp declaration as follows (global variable):

```
int *temp;
```

3- modify `input(int d)` function as follows (tested on Visual Studio 2010):

```
  void input(int d)
    {
        int x=0;
        temp=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*d);
        for(x=0;x<d;x++)
        {
            printf("Input temperature in Celsius for #%d day",x+1);
            scanf("%d",&temp[x]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, don't forget to deallocate *temp* at the end of `main(...)`.  Second, I would advise both allocating and deallocating *temp* within the `main(...)` function, instead of allocating in `input(...)` and deallocating in `main(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate the "array" dynamically on the heap after you read the size.

Comment: Why not just allocate the array with the needed size in the first place?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen You're right, I didn't read the code and didn't see that the size is read. Updated answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't change anything else so you may see it clearly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   //here
void input(int);
int *temp=0;  //here
int d;
void main()
{
    int x=0;
    float avg=0,t=0;
    printf("\nHow many days : ");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    temp=malloc(d * sizeof(int));  //here
    input(d);
    conv();
    for(x=0;x<d;x++)
    {
        t=t+temp[x];
    }
    avg=t/d;
    printf("Avarage is %f",avg);
    getch();
}
void input(int d)
{
    int x=0;
    for(x=0;x<d;x++)
    {
        printf("Input temperature in Celsius for #%d day",x+1);
        scanf("%d",&temp[x]);
    }
}
void conv()
{
    int x=0;
    for(x=0;x<d;x++)
    {
        temp[x]=1.8*temp[x]+32;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's got some error "malloc should have prototype" how to fix it.. plz

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late to answer but...
If you work with small embedded system you might not have malloc and free functions.
So you have to sacrifice memory for `366 * sizeof(your_type)`, define it statically and use as a circular buffer. Then you can always slice it by number of days you need to calculate an average value.
Of course this makes natural constrains. You can define it by yourself.